# Get administrator component value from the front-end

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

How can I get a specific value from a component in the administrator from the front-end without using the database?

Comment: Are you referring to a component parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
JComponentHelper::getParams('component_name')->get('field_name');
```

Hope this helps people out :).